# The popup's barrier covering the underneath keyboard in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, keyboard

[the popup's barrier covering the underneath keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Poe5X.jpg)

Is it possible in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

the question is why you show the popup without hiding the keyboard first, i don't think it's a good UX, you can hide the keyboard with unfocusing the textfield